# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget. 'data != null' and Error logging in

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to perform user login with my flutter app but then I keep getting data != null error and that a Text Widget must have a non-null string.

Upon further debugging, I realized the response['message'] is printing a null value so I implement a condition to check if it's not null before proceeding but yet still it keeps giving me the same error.

When I use response['message'].toString(), it still gives the same error.

**this is the full error being thrown** 'data != null': A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

*the issue seems to be from the response['message'] but I just can't seem to find ways to solve it*

**This is Auth controller class**

```
  class AuthController extends GetxController {
  AuthService authService = AuthService();
  ProjectApis projectApis = ProjectApis();

  String name = '';
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String confirmPassword = '';
  var isPasswordHidden = true.obs;

  
  Future loginUser(BuildContext context) async {
    buildLoader(context, message: 'Loading...');

    http.Response response = await authService.signInUser(
      email,
      password,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      debugPrint(responseData.toString());
      debugPrint(responseData['message']);
      if (responseData["status"] == true) {
        User user = User.fromJson(responseData);

        UserPreferences().setUser(user);
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Get.offAll(() => BottomNavigation());
        return;
      } else {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(responseData['message']),
        ));

        return;
      }
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);

      showErrorDialog(context, message: "Server Error");
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

**This is the sign in function**

```
Future<http.Response> signInUser(
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    Map data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    };
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var url = Uri.parse(projectApis.loginUrl);

    var response = await client.post(
      url,
      body: body,
      headers: projectApis.headers,
    );
    return response;
  }
```

**This is the User model class**

```
User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {
  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.passwordConfirm,
    this.token,
  });

  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? passwordConfirm;
  String? token;

  String applicationDirPath = "";

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        email: json["email"],
        password: json["password"],
        passwordConfirm: json["passwordConfirm"],
        token: json["token"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "passwordConfirm": passwordConfirm,
        "token": token,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use null-operator like here

```
response['message'] ?? ''
```

If left side was null the right side will assing
But you can use this just if you are sure this happen because of this line

- [read in medium](https://jelenaaa.medium.com/what-are-in-dart-df1f11706dd6?utm_source=pocket_mylist)

Comment: @Alaindeseine thank y'all for your suggestions, I have implemented them but I am still unable to log users into the app.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is with the `Text(responseData['message']),` line.

Dart can't be sure that me `message` key exist on responseData Map. So `Text(responseData['message']),` can be null which is bad for null safety.

Just do:

```
String message = responseData['message'] ?? '';
```

The `??` operator will return  an empty string in case `ResponseData['message']` is null.

Then replace in your Text widget:

```
Text(message),
```

Comment: thank y'all for your suggestions, I have implemented them but I am still unable to log users in to the app.

Answer (score 1):

Text widget doesn't accept nullable String, and reading map can provide null value. You can provide default value on null case like

`Text(myMap["key"]??"defaultValue")`

And for perser you can do

```dart
 if (responseData["status"]  != null && responseData["status"]==true ) {
```

Comment: @Alaindeseine thank y'all for your suggestions, I have implemented them but I am still unable to log users into the app.

Comment: Are you  getting  data to the model class?

Comment: It suppose to get it from the User model class

Comment: I have edited the question and added the User model class.

Comment: model accelpt nullabel data, sholdnt be issue Can you debug/print the `user` from `User user = User.fromJson(responseData);`

Comment: debugPrint("print this " + user.toString()); it does not print any value

Comment: override `toString` on `User` class,  also now put a general print statement `Map<String, dynamic> responseData`. A better way of doing this adding breaking points on debug more

Comment: I have done that but it does not seem to work. I am very grateful for your help, please. I will try a different approach and if it does work, I will provide the answer here as well.

Comment: I have been able to resolve the error. I had to tackle it right from the backend to the frontend. Thanks